# exception when using tesseract ocr by java

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract

i am trying to use tesseract ocr and ive got this exception while running it on eclipse.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.copyJarResourceToDirectory(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.extractTessResources(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Unknown Source)
at Run.main(Run.java:42)
```

exception throwing code is -

```
    Tesseract instance = Tesseract.getInstance();
    try {
        String captcha = instance.doOCR(image);
        System.out.println(captcha);
```

first line is 40.
it used to say 40 in the problem but now after playing with it it says 42.

ive got tess4j.jar , jai_imageio , jna.jar as referenced libs.

what do i need to do to make the OCR work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
`org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils`
```

It appears as if you don't have `Apache`s commons-io.jar. You can find it: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to download the [`Commons IO`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) package and add it to your class path.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi) as referenced libs too.